# PrimeNG Dialog Animation

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to use a shake animation on a dialog. I can animate the contents of the dialog, but cant manage to animate the complete dialog.

```
<p-dialog header="Anim Dialog" [(visible)]="displayDialog">

<p [@shake]="shakeState" (@shake.done)="shakeDone()">Shake</p>

<p [@bounce]="bounceState" (@bounce.done)="bounceDone()">Bounce</p>

</p-dialog>
```

I've found some answers online, but none of them seem to work :( Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use css

put this in styles.css/scss

```
.p-dialog {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

this applies to all dialog, you may choose a css class example

```
.p-dialog.shake-in
```

and add a style class to dialog

```
<p-dialog header="Header" [(visible)]="displayBasic" [style]="{width: '50vw'}" [baseZIndex]="10000" styleClass="shake-in">
...
```

stackblitz here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dialog-demo-iekqph?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Your example at least works, so I'm able to replicate. Will look into it this day.